# How can I duplicate a task?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Sometimes customers send over multiple quote requests (which we log in SharePoint of course). The data from that customer ends up being mostly the same for all quotes, but they have to be logged as separate jobs. same requestor, same e-mail, same sales perseon, etc. So, is there a way to enter all of the info in a new task, then duplicate or copy that task for the next one? Seems like something that should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about copying list items?
If yes, the simplest way may be to:

1. Go to the list
2. Click on the LIST tab, and then on "Quick Edit" button.
3. Mark the columns you want to copy and copy the item using CTRL+C, CTRL+V:

[image]

If you are looking for a programmatic solution, you can retrieve the items and add:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks

If the task you are talking about is by any chance a file, then for files there is a dedicated [copying method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.copyto.aspx):

```
$file.CopyTo()
```